# How to Sum tables with Left Join and pre aggregate

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables to calculate payments, received and paid:

1. Company

| idcompany | company |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | APPLE |
| 2 | GOOGLE |
| 3 | MICROSOFT |
| 4 | STEAM |
| 5 | AMAZON |
| 6 | LG |

2. Pay:

| id | company | dueday | valuep |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | APPLE | 03/10/2022 | 200,00 |
| 2 | APPLE | 04/10/2022 | 600,00 |
| 3 | GOOGLE | 04/10/2022 | 600,00 |
| 4 | MICROSOFT | 04/10/2022 | 500,00 |
| 5 | MICROSOFT | 04/10/2022 | 60,00 |
| 6 | APPLE | 04/10/2022 | 100,00 |

3.Receive:

| idconta | company | issuedate | valuer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 104 | MICROSOFT | 03/10/2022 | 70000,00 |
| 106 | STEAM | 03/10/2022 | 15000,00 |
| 107 | STEAM | 03/10/2022 | 42000,00 |
| 108 | AMAZON | 03/10/2022 | 46000,00 |
| 109 | LG | 03/10/2022 | 3200,00 |

I need to make a report with amount paid and received during a certain period, but somehow its duplicating sum and I getting this result:

| company | value_pay | value_receive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AMAZON | NULL | 46000.00 |
| APPLE | 900.00 | NULL |
| GOOGLE | 600.00 | NULL |
| LG | NULL | 3200.00 |
| MICROSOFT | 560.00 | 140000.00 |
| SHOPPING | NULL | 20000.00 |
| STEAM | NULL | 57000.00 |

I tried this query:

```
SELECT o.company, 
       SUM(n.valuep) AS value_pay, 
       SUM(r.valuer) AS value_receive 
FROM app_company AS o 
LEFT JOIN app_pay AS n ON o.idcompany=n.company AND (date(n.duedate) BETWEEN '2022-10-01' AND '2022-10-30') 
LEFT JOIN app_receive AS r ON o.idcompany=r.company AND (date(r.issuedate) BETWEEN '2022-10-01' AND '2022-10-30') 
GROUP BY o.company
```

I tried LEFT JOIN to get all results even if it is empty in one of columns, I tried to pre-aggregate, but I could not get my query to work. I am missing something.

Comment: Please include the result you want, not the result you don't want.

Comment: the result I want is to sum paid and received bills, the result would be the table above, but my query it is calculating wrong, with duplication of values. If you take a look at table 3. Receive, the total Microsoft bills would be $70,000 not 140,000 like the result table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the aggregation on the subqueries and then join .

```
SELECT o.company, 
       value_pay, 
       value_receive 
FROM app_company AS o 
LEFT JOIN  (select sum(valuep) as value_pay,
                   company
            from app_pay
            where date(dueday) BETWEEN '2022-10-01' AND '2022-10-30'
            group by company
             ) AS n ON o.company=n.company 
LEFT JOIN  (select sum(valuer)  AS value_receive ,
                   company
            from app_receive
            where date(issuedate) BETWEEN '2022-10-01' AND '2022-10-30' 
            group by company
            )  AS r ON o.company=r.company 
order by o.company asc   ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/0mVKI_tF

Comment: Thank you Ergest Basha, worked perfect! I will buy you a coffee.